# Dissolution of CO2 over time in a high pH solution

Tags: biochemistry, ph, gas-laws, gas

I asked this question in the biology stack-exchange but thought it might be more appropriate here.

I am running a batch experiment using penicillin bottles where I have bacteria growing for 21 days in a highly alkaline media (pH 10). I am measuring the CO2 and O2 content in the headspace over time, but I am specially interested in the CO2 production. Usually I can simply use the CO2 content measured with a gas-chromatographer (GC) but because of the pH of my media, the CO2 will be dissolved into my media. This I have seen in the sharp drop of pH over time as well.

I want then, to calculate the amount of CO2 that has dissolved into my media. I know I require Dalton's Law of partial pressures and Henry's constant/Law. The thing is that, I am a bit confused because as I measured the pressure inside my closed bottles, the pressure in these bottles became negative. So my calculations are returning a negative value for my concentration of gas in the solution. Furthermore, I do not know if the formulas I used (Dalton  and Henry), take into consideration the pH of my aqueous media.

Comment: Note that more than 99,9% of the dissolved carbon dioxide will be present at pH 10 as bicarbonate and carbonate anions, so the effective gas solubility would be more than 1000 times bigger than in pure water. // See [Carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid) and there embedded chart [Carbonate_system_of_seawater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid#/media/File:Carbonate_system_of_seawater.svg)

Comment: pH 10 solutions would absorb practically all CO2 that comes in contact to them, possibly causing suction/underpressure. // By other words, you do not deal just with gas dissolution equilibrium, but also with three chemical equilibrii, two of them pH dependent as acid-base chemical reactions.

Comment: Wouldn't a "sharp drop of pH over time" have an effect on bacteria growth?